# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Electrical Engineering's [second moderator election](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: W5VO] [image: clabacchio]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) shortly - please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Comment: Congratulations guys. You will now be assimilated into the collective.... Resistance is futile....

Comment: At least I wasn't last this time. The streak continues!

Comment: Another two lost to the dark side... :-) Just kidding - well done, I'm sure it's a good thing for the site. Commiserations to Madmanguruman (third time lucky?) and Jippie.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I cant believe that no one up voted your comment.

Comment: @Kortuk - I just did!

Comment: @Olin - Do you mean [this](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/60fd/)?

Comment: Well deserved guys!

Answer (score 9):

## Congratulations

Good job community. You had to pick 2 users from a pool of 4 great users, but regardless of who won, we are one of the few communities that had all great candidates run!

Thanks for taking the time Jippie and Madmanguruman. Keep taking part in the site and keep using moderator tools, voting to close, flagging and when our site gets so great we need more moderators next year due to load I am sure you will be back!